# How to include nested data in a mixed-effects model using R?

Tags: r, mixed-model, random-effects-model

I am analyzing data from bird foraging surveys using the lme4 package in R and I am interested in the effects of field size (area), among other variables, on swallow rate of use. The surveys took place over 2 years, and I’d like to include year as a fixed effect in the model. Each field (n = 31) was surveyed 6 times. So the data look like:

```
Field   Survey  Year    Area    RateOfUse
1       1       2017    3.06    0
1       2       2017    3.06    0.327
1       3       2017    3.06    0.327
1       4       2017    3.06    0.327
1       5       2017    3.06    3.92
1       6       2017    3.06    0.327
1       1       2018    3.06    0
1       2       2018    3.06    0.392
1       3       2018    3.06    2.55
1       4       2018    3.06    2.94
1       5       2018    3.06    0.588
1       6       2018    3.06    0
2
...
```

In order to include field as a random effect (accounting for the fact that each field has data from 6 surveys), does this make sense:

```
lme(RateOfUse ~ Area + Year, random = ~1|Field/Survey)
```

Alternatively, I could included Survey as a fixed effect to account for the fact that rate of use might have dropped off during later surveys:

```
lme(RateOfUse ~ Area + Year + Survey, random=~1|Field)
```

I also have a separate variable Field_Survey which is

```
Field_Survey    Year
1_1             2017
1_2             2017
1_3             2017
1_4             2017
1_5             2017
1_6             2017
1_1             2018
1_2             2018
1_3             2018
1_4             2018
1_5             2018
1_6             2018
...
```

So instead I could do something like:

```
lme(RateOfUse ~ Area + Year, random = ~1|Field_Survey)
```

Which of these models makes more sense? Is 31 groupings (fields) way too many? I am a bit rusty with mixed effects models and want to make sure I'm thinking about this correctly.

Comment: Your model code is using `nlme` not `lme4`. Take a look [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228800/crossed-vs-nested-random-effects-how-do-they-differ-and-how-are-they-specified/228814#228814) for how to specify clustering in `lme4`

Answer (score 2):

Note that random effects terms are translated to correlations. In particular, by including a random effect (e.g., a random intercept) in the `Field` level, you assume that `RateOfUse` measurements within the same `Field` are correlated. And by including a nested random intercept for `Survey` within `Field`, you assume that `RateOfUse` measurements from the same `Survey` within the same `Field` are more strongly correlated than `RateOfUse` measurements from different `Surveys` within the same `Field`.

Now, the question is, is this the case for your data? You can test data using a likelihood ratio test, i.e., by comparing the two models:

```
fm1 <- lme(RateOfUse ~ Area + Year, random = ~ 1 | Field)
fm2 <- lme(RateOfUse ~ Area + Year, random = ~ 1 | Field / Survey)
anova(fm1, fm2)
```

When you include the `Survey` as a fixed-effect, this translates to a different average for the `RateOfUse` per `Survey` level controlled for `Area` and `Year`. (**Note:** this will depend on whether `Survey` is a factor or not; if not, then `Survey` is included as a numeric variable, and you assume a linear relationship between the average `RateOfUse` and the `Survey` levels).